# NullReferenceException. Object reference not set to an instance of an object C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, nullreferenceexception

I get error each time. I couldn't find a solution to it. 
When I build the solution, it succeeds, but then it gives a server error on the line below in model class:

```
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
```

**this is the View:**

```
@{foreach(var item in Model.Items) 
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DepartmentId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SignNo)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndDate)
            </td>

        </tr>
    }
}
```

**MODEL**

```
public class ListTable
    {
        public class Item
        {
            public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
            public string DepartmentId { get; set; }
            public string SignNo { get; set; }
            public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
            public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        }

        public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

    }
}
```

How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: Have you assigned any value to the Items property?

Comment: Can you show the action code where model is created?

Comment: no i havent assigned anything to it! is dat causing the error?

Comment: @saumyavishwakarma erm... yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a new instance of the list to the property first:

```
public List<Item> { get; set; }

// in constructor:
public ListTable()
{
    Items = new List<Item>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Class  is a non-primitive datatype, you cant just have the property over an object  without instantiating it.

Below code will work:

```
     List<Item> Items = new List<Items>(); 
     public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
```